# Handling two consecutive errors

Tags: go

While reading a code, I ran into the following error handling currently implemented in the code:

```
    nodes, err := model.AllNodes()
    links, err := model.AllLinks()
    if err != nil {
        // Do stuff
    }
```

I'm curious to know if the above error handling can create unpredictable results. I have this alternative in mind:

```
    nodes, err1 := model.AllNodes()
    if err1 != nil {
        // Do stuff
    }
    links, err2 := model.AllLinks()
    if err2 != nil {
        // Do stuff
    }
```

Or maybe this:

```
    nodes, err1 := model.AllNodes()
    links, err2 := model.AllLinks()
    if err1 != nil || err2 != nil {
        // Do stuff
    }
```

I'm not sure, please help me to know if the current implemented error handling can cause a bug. Please let me know if there is a better alternative. Thanks.

Comment: The original code is incorrect. You're correct that it's not checking the first error

Comment: The original version would definitely be picked up by any linter, I'm a little surprised it would even compile with an unused variable assignment.

Comment: @Adrian: It's not unused, and it's only an ineffectual assignment if `err` wasn't already used--and even that level of ineffectual assignment is not caught by the standard linter, AFAIK.

Comment: It's assigned to, then immediately assigned to again. That's the textbook definition of ineffectual assignment.

Comment: @Adrian: Perhaps, but it won't be caught by the Go linter.

Comment: Yes, it's not invalid, nor a vet error, but I have seen a tool specifically to find these: github.com/gordonklaus/ineffassign

Comment: @user3405291 you should go with your first alternative. Say AllLinks is doing a bunch of expensive stuff, if AllNodes fails you can return early and not waste resources, also with this approach you don't need to number tag your error variable.

Comment: @mkopriva Right. I will submit a pull request with my first alternative. Thanks.

Comment: @user3405291: note with your first example if you're making a PR, it's idiomatic to use just `err` for both as you're handing them immediately after assignment.

Comment: @JimB Thanks. I used just `err` for both, as you suggested.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are right to be concerned. The first error is not being handled at all, which is *probably* a bug.  If the author intended not to check that error, it would be much more clear to do so explicitly:

```
nodes, _ := model.AllNodes()
links, err := model.AllLinks()
if err != nil {
    // Do stuff
}
```

Comment: However, _DO NOT DO THIS_.  Throwing errors into underscores is 99.9% of the time wrong and will lead to difficult-to-debug problems down the line when that thing you're not checking the error on actually returns an error.

Comment: @Kaedys: I think you may be overstating the case. There are legitimate times to ignore errors (this probably isn't one of them... but that's not really the point).

Comment: They exist, but they are the vanishing minority.  If a function returns an error, it's because it _can_ fail.  The fundamental semantic is that you cannot rely on the function succeeding or any of the other return values until you check the error.  If you fail to check the error, you're simply hoping it works, and failures will be difficult to diagnose later when assumptions you made fail to hold up.  Partly, though, that was based on just how many questions I see out here where the answer, fundamentally, is "you're ignoring an error that would have told you what's wrong".